# Exception at build.gradle with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3

Tags: java, exception, gradle, intellij-idea

After I update my IntelliJ Idea Community Edition from Version 2018.2 to Version 2018.3 my project don't work anymore. The problem is located at the build.gradle, because it indicates to me, for example: Cannot resolve symbol 'buildscricpt'. And this for every symbol in build.gradle.

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        maven
        {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}
plugins
{
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
}
group 'de.uniks'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'de.uniks.MainApp'

apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'

repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
    maven
    {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }
}

ext.platform = osdetector.os != 'osx' ? osdetector.os : 'mac'

dependencies
{
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile 'org.fulib:fulib:1.0.+'

    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:${platform}"
    implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:${platform}"
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
}
```

This is the error message:

```
exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:267)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:65)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:185)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.configure.KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(KotlinAndroidMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:51)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:96)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:62)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:381)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:75)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:738)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:721)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:216)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:140)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:75)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:166)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:554)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:659)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:727)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:403)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you use Gradle 5 version? Could be the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28515

Answer (score -2):

Try closing the IDE then deleting or renaming the .gradle folder located in C:/Users//.gradle and restart the IDE.